# Google Vertex AI custom job authentication works differently when adds google-cloud-storage dependency in docker image

Tags: docker, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying the run vertex ai custom job using docker image. My use case is reading data from bigquery table and loading existing model from gcs bucket.

While I ran data gathering part in which I included google-cloud-bigquery dependency in docker image, it could able to authenticate and run the query on BigQuery.

But when I included google-cloud-storage dependency in lib, it is giving error

```
google.auth.exception.RefreshError: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true 
from the Google Engine metadata service. Compute engine metadata server unavailable
```

Although I haven't added any code for reading gcs bucket only the dependency.

I was expecting that it could run the query on BigQuery as it was doing earlier without google-cloud-storage lib